# z3py BitVector mixed with integer operations

Tags: z3py

Having a (`lst_v`) list of BitVectors and a (`lst_b`) list of boolean expressions values.  How do you perform the following operations using z3py:

- use the `lst_b` to mask elements in `lst_v`. The masking needed to use `And` function since the boolean expression needs to be solved in the final step.
- compute the the xor of all remaining elements
- test the all the bits are set in the result by using the `Solve` class of z3py.

A variation of the problem is to exchange xor with addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve; but perhaps the following will get you going:

```
from z3 import *

# Assume we have a list of 3 32-bit values
x, y, z = BitVecs('x y z', 32)
lst_v = [x, y, z]

# Corresponding booleans:
mx, my, mz = Bools('mx my mz')
lst_b = [mx, my, mz]

# 32-bit zero
zero = BitVecVal(0, 32)

# Mask
masked = [If(b, v, zero) for (b, v) in zip(lst_b, lst_v)]

# Xor reduce
final = reduce(lambda x, y: x^y, masked, zero)

# 32-bit all 1's
allOnes = BitVecVal(-1, 32)

s = Solver()
s.add(final == allOnes)

# make it interesting, assert some known values and constraints
s.add(x == BitVecVal(123212, 32))
s.add(UGT(x + y,  z+12))
s.add(ULT(y, allOnes))

if s.check() == sat:
   print s.model()
else:
   print "No solution"
```

When I run this, I get:

```
[mz = True,
 mx = False,
 my = True,
 z = 2147479427,
 y = 2147487868,
 x = 123212]
```

which suggests, I should XOR y and z as 32 bit values; which gives 4294967295, which has all its bits set as a 32-bit quantity.